# IP Storing In MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an application that will retrieve your username for you when you try to log in by using your ip address. I am doing this to prevent multiple signups and similar things. But when I try to insert an IP as varbinary, it says:
IP column cannot be null. I am using this query to insert it:
Error

```
INSERT INTO  `maindb`.`users` (

`id` ,
`username` ,
`password` ,
`email` ,
`ip` ,
`status` ,
`credits`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  'Dummy',  'dummy',  'dummy@example.com', UNHEX(  '0.0.0.0' ) ,  '1',  '0'
)
```

MySQL said:

> #1048 - Column 'ip' cannot be null

Also, please note that I followed a tutorial to get this query so don't ask me how I got this query.
Please Help, Thanks

Comment: why do you need to unhex it anyways ?

Comment: Beware any methods for binding users to IP addresses, as an IP cannot uniquely identify a user (NAT, VPN, etc). That said, MySQL supplies [`INET_NTOA(),INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html) for converting IP addresses to store as integer representations.

Comment: I followed a tutorial. I need a way to store user data but I don't know how to use MySQL, just PHP.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`UNHEX()` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex):

> The characters in the argument string must be legal hexadecimal
>   digits: '0' .. '9', 'A' .. 'F', 'a' .. 'f'. If the argument contains
>   any nonhexadecimal digits, the result is NULL

Including the dots (".") in the `UNHEX()` function will make it return NULL. Apparently, your `ip` column is set to reject NULL values.

Comment: Can you tell me HOW I CAN store an IP?

Comment: There are a number of ways. See the comment from @MichaelBerkowski regarding the use of `INET_ATON()` for inserting IPv4 addresses as integers. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

Comment: @user3155126 either use `INET_NTOA()` / `INET_ATON()` which is supplied by MySQL or change the column type to `VARCHAR` and store it as a string

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. If your `id` is set to auto-increment, you need not insert "NULL" for ID.
2. UNHEX() is returning null - why don't you pull down the user's IP address for this?  In PHP you can use `echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` for this.

Comment: I am insert fake data to test it, I already have the application working other than the MySQL error.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO  `maindb`.`users` (

`id` ,
`username` ,
`password` ,
`email` ,
`ip` ,
`status` ,
`credits`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  'Dummy',  'dummy',  'dummy@example.com', sprintf("%u",ip2long('0.0.0.0')) ,  '1',  '0'
);
```

use [ip2long](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) php function(if in php)

other wise use INET_ATON() on mysql

```
  INSERT INTO  `maindb`.`users` (

    `id` ,
    `username` ,
    `password` ,
    `email` ,
    `ip` ,
    `status` ,
    `credits`
    )
    VALUES (
    NULL ,  'Dummy',  'dummy',  'dummy@example.com', INET_ATON('0.0.0.0') ,  '1',  '0'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your argument to `UNHEX()` is wrong, because according to documentation of UNHEX(),argument should be `'0' .. '9', 'A' .. 'F', 'a' .. 'f'`. So it return NULL.

If you want to store ip adress, you could get ip adress from server variable

```
 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 INSERT INTO  `maindb`.`users` (

 `id` ,
 `username` ,
 `password` ,
 `email` ,
 `ip` ,
 `status` ,
 `credits`
 )
 VALUES (
 NULL ,  'Dummy',  'dummy',  'dummy@example.com', '$ip' ,  '1',  '0'
 )
```